# Unable to disable git log-in shell to prevent shell access

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, gitolite

I have set up git+gitolite on my raspberry pi (Debian, wheezy)
I have a git user and wanted to add some extra security by disabling the log-in shell for it. According to documentation out there it should be plain sailing so I did;

```
sudo usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell git
```

and I added /usr/bin/git-shells to my /etc/shells file.
However, when I run git clone or ssh -vT git@myhost the error I get is

```
fatal: unrecognized command '/home/git/bin/gitolite-shell MYUSERNAME'
```

I have also changed the shell to the gitolite-shell but this gives me an error stating that "-c" is an unrecognized command.

Is this something others have experienced and can provide help about?

Comment: Btw, I also added a git-shell-commands directory with a help script to /home/git but to no avail

Comment: And another update: the problem seems to be related to gitolite; the authorized_keys entries for git point to /home/git/bin/gitolite-shell for their command. I tried to copy gitolite-shell into /home/git/git-shell-commands but that fails because it tries to include files from relative locations. Short of mirroring the whole gitolite dependency tree this approach therefore doesn't seem to work either...

Answer (score 0):

The answer I am offering myself is to delete the password for the git user

```
sudo passwd -d git
```

And thereby disabling log-in. This seems to work as expected.